# Finding points in a coordinate system based on equations

Tags: r, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have a number of inequalities that I would like to translate to points into a 3-d coordinate system, `x`, `y` and `z`.

I need to find all possible points that fulfill all my inequalities, save each point, and then plot it as a 3d-scatterplot.

Simplified data example:

```
#Inequalities (I have several more)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.1), 
  y = c(0.7, 0.11, -0.25), 
  z = c(-0.5, -0.02, 1),  
  v = c(90, 2500, 350))

# Limits of the coordinate system
x.lim <- seq(-100, 100, by = 1) 
y.lim <- seq(-100, 100, by = 1) 
z.lim <- seq(-50, 50, by = 1) 

# Basic check - must be true for all points: 
df$x + df$y + df$z < df$v

# Looping through all points of the coordinate system 
# no need to test row 2, # if the first row is false

df$x*-100 + df$y*-100 + df$z*-50 < df$v 
# if all conditions are true, save the point to a list/matrix to be able to plot it
df$x*-99 + df$y*-100 + df$z*-50 < df$v
#...
df$x*-100 + df$y*-99 + df$z*-50 < df$v
df$x*-99 + df$y*-98 + df$z*-50 < df$v
#...
df$x*100 + df$y*100 + df$z*50 < df$v
```

So, in the end I would have a matrix m - that would contain all test for true variables, which would look something like this:

```
m
x        y     z
-100   -100   -50
99     -100   -50
...
100     100    50
```

In the end I would be able to plot all my TRUE-TRUE-TRUE results into a 3d-scatterplot such as:

```
plot3d(x = m[, 1], y = m[, 2], z = m[, 3], col = "blue", size = 4, 
       xlim = c(-100, 100), ylim = c(-100, 100), zlim = c(-50, 50))
```

I potentially have a lot more equations and much larger coordinate system, so speed is also a issue I am looking at. My main problem is how to write a conditional loop and look at all the different values that are available and then save the correct ones into a matrix.

Comment: protip: use `with` e.g. `with(df, -100*x-100*y-50*z<v)`